# "relation does not exist" trying to import mysql dump into postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, import

environment:

```
ubuntu 10.04
mysql server 5.1.69 
postgres 9.2
```

Here's the sequence of steps:

1. created a new postgres database, myDatabase
2. executed this command: `mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=postgresql myDatabase > mydump.sql`
3. executed this command: `psql -h localhost -d myDatabase -U postgres`
4. At postgres prompt, executed these commands:

```
    SET standard_conforming_strings = 'off';    
    SET backslash_quote = 'on';     
    \i mydump.sql;
```

At this point, the process began, and after getting tons of

```
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
psql:mydump.sql:196: WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: ...012053',50.18,50.36,49.4,49.69,59592,184824),(115,'\"2012060...
```

I get

```
psql:mydump.sql:196: ERROR:  relation "pricedata" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "pricedata" VALUES (113,'19981102',0.6275,0.6275...
```

I checked the mydump.sql file, and it has a CREATE TABLE "pricedata", but obviously this didn't have the desired effect on the postgres db.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to get this to work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Among other problems, MySQL doesn't order trable creations according to constraints between them. Which means that if there's a dependecy A => B, not necessarily MySQL is going to create A before B. This is troublesome for Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work. Don't even try feeding `mysqldump` output directly into `psql`. You'll need to dump schema and data separately, convert the schema either by hand or with a tool, load the converted schema into PostgreSQL then load the dumped data.

`mysqldump`'s compatibility flags are moderately useful for dumping *data* but pretty useless for dumping schema definitions.

The "relation does not exist" error will be a follow-up error caused by a prior one. Try running with `psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1 ....` .